# What might be causing equal variances all over the predictions? (GP / BO)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, gaussian-process

I have 1D data here. I create labels with a comparison of consecutive pairs. I use the value gamma to decide the label. If data at row x is gamma much bigger than data at row x+1, the label is -1. If the opposite, the label is 1. If the difference between them is smaller than gamma, I say 0. Here is a sample data.

```
# Define parameters
N = 1001  # Number of samples
lower_bound = 120
upper_bound = 160
value_range = upper_bound - lower_bound
gamma = 0.1 * value_range  # 10% of the value range
noise_std = 0.05 * value_range

# Initialize the Latin Hypercube Sampler
sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=1, seed=42)  # 1D sample
samples = sampler.random(n=N)  # Generate samples

# Scale samples to the desired range
scaled_samples = qmc.scale(samples, lower_bound, upper_bound)

scaled_samples = scaled_samples + np.random.normal(0, noise_std, scaled_samples.shape)

# Shuffle the samples
np.random.shuffle(scaled_samples)

# Flatten the scaled_samples for easier handling
flat_samples = scaled_samples.flatten()

# Compute the differences between consecutive values and label them
labels = []
for i in range(len(flat_samples)-1):
    diff = flat_samples[i+1] - flat_samples[i]
    if diff > gamma:
        labels.append(1)  # Second trial is gamma much bigger
    elif diff < -gamma:
        labels.append(-1)  # First trial is gamma much bigger
    else:
        labels.append(0)  # Difference is smaller than gamma

X = scaled_samples
y = labels # Check the balance
unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
balance_check = dict(zip(unique, counts))
print(f"Label counts: {balance_check}")

# Normalize features of the original data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1, 1))  # X is the original data
X_train = torch.tensor(X_scaled, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
```

I want to train a GP model here. I wrote a custom likelihood to calculate probabilities.

Here is the GP model

```
class VariationalGPModel(gpytorch.models.ApproximateGP):
    def __init__(self, inducing_points, mean_module, covar_module):
        variational_distribution = gpytorch.variational.CholeskyVariationalDistribution(inducing_points.size(0))
        variational_strategy = gpytorch.variational.VariationalStrategy(
            self, inducing_points, variational_distribution, learn_inducing_locations=True
        )
        super().__init__(variational_strategy)
        self.mean_module = mean_module
        self.covar_module = covar_module

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        covar_x = covar_x.add_jitter(1e-4)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
```

Here is the likelihood I created

```
class CustomLikelihood(Likelihood):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.register_parameter(name="gamma", parameter=torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1)))
        self.register_parameter(name="raw_gamma", parameter=torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1)))
        self.sigma = 1.0
        
    @property
    def gamma(self):
        # Apply transformation to ensure gamma is non-negative
        return torch.exp(self.raw_gamma)
        
    def forward(self, x, y):
        sigma = torch.sqrt(torch.tensor(2 * self.sigma))
        normal_dist = Normal(torch.tensor(0.0), sigma)
        gamma = self.gamma # maybe some modifications here
        
        y = y[:-1] # remove last virtual label. required to work with elbo
        
        # Ensure that prediction_x and prediction_x_prime are tensors, not methods
        if callable(x):
            x = x()

        prediction_x = x[:-1]
        prediction_x_prime = x[1:]

            
        # Calculate probabilities for each label
        prob_y_minus_1 = normal_dist.cdf(prediction_x - prediction_x_prime - gamma)
           
        prob_y_0 = torch.clamp(normal_dist.cdf(gamma - (prediction_x_prime - prediction_x)) - \
                               normal_dist.cdf(-gamma - (prediction_x_prime - prediction_x)), min=0)

        prob_y_1 = normal_dist.cdf(prediction_x_prime - prediction_x - gamma)
        
        # Ensure y is a flat vector
        y_flat = y.squeeze()

        # Then use torch.where
        likelihood = torch.where(y_flat == -1, prob_y_minus_1, torch.where(y_flat == 0, prob_y_0, prob_y_1))
        
        eps = 1e-6
        log_likelihood = torch.log(likelihood + eps)
        
        total_log_likelihood = log_likelihood.sum()
        
        return total_log_likelihood

    def expected_log_prob(self, observations, function_dist, *args, **kwargs):
        # Note that we need to pass the observations (labels) here as well.
        total_log_likelihood = self.forward(function_dist.mean, observations, **kwargs)
    
        # Sums the selected log probabilities, giving a single value representing the expected log likelihood.
        return total_log_likelihood  # Summing over all data points
```

Here is the training part

```
random_indices = torch.randperm(X_train.size(0))[:num_inducing_points]
inducing_points_x = X_train[random_indices, :]
mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel())

# Instantiate two models with shared parameters
model = VariationalGPModel(inducing_points_x, mean_module, covar_module)

likelihood = CustomLikelihood()

y_train_extended = torch.cat([y_train, torch.tensor([[999.0]])], dim=0) # the added label will be removed. it is added for elbo function
y_train_extended_squeezed = y_train_extended.squeeze()
mll = gpytorch.mlls.VariationalELBO(likelihood, model, num_data=y_train_extended.size(0))

model = model.to(device)
likelihood = likelihood.to(device)
X_train = X_train.to(device)
y_train = y_train.to(device)
y_train_extended_squeezed = y_train_extended_squeezed.to(device)

# Ensure optimizer is aware of all parameters on the correct device
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
    {'params': model.parameters()},
    {'params': [likelihood.raw_gamma, *likelihood.parameters()]}
], lr=learning_rate)

model.train()
likelihood.train()
loss_vec = []
    
for i in range(num_iterations):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Forward pass through the model
    output = model(X_train)
    
    # Compute the loss using VariationalELBO
    loss = -mll(output, y_train_extended_squeezed)

    # Backward pass and optimization step
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    loss_vec.append(loss.item())
```

At the end I do predictions and I check the variances like that:

```
# Ensure the model is in evaluation mode
model.eval()
likelihood.eval()

# Generate predictions
with torch.no_grad(), gpytorch.settings.fast_pred_var():
    predictions = model(X_train)

# Extract predicted means and variances
predicted_means = predictions.mean
predicted_variances = predictions.variance
```

My problem is even though the mean predictions are great, the created samples look bad since the uncertainty is equal all over the input points. What might be causing this issue?

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand: the code you've provided doesn't do any GP fitting, right? And the question you have is about the GP fitting? Any chance you could provide that code?

Comment: @JohnMadden yes sure editing the question

Comment: Thanks for providing the rest of the code. But now that I have run it my first question is actually about your data generation process. It seems like you are generating your response $y=f(x)$ not as a function of the $x$, but rather as a function of $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, where the data $x$ have been shuffled such that the indices $i$ are random. This does not align your GP assumptions, which assumes you are modeling a function on your input space. But more importantly, it's difficult to understand why you would be doing this: what real world situation are you trying to simulate here?

Comment: @JohnMadden thank you for your reply. Shuffling and then deciding the labels are okay for this synthetic data. I can not share the exact situation, but I imagine consecutive trials that give a result, and I want to test the difference between these results. In reality, the outputs are not values but some preferential data, so I simulate them like that in this case. Imagine a case that we are determining the beauty of 2 people and possible outcomes are more beautiful, similar and uglier

Comment: OK in such a case, we will want to provide both inputs which are compared to the gaussian process, and not only the first input as you are currently doing. Make sense? And possibly in both orderings (we would need to use a GP which is input-order equivariant to precisely deal with this).

Comment: @JohnMadden thank you for your reply. actually, in the likelihood, I have x and x', which is the second input. I mean, normally, beauties are always decided based on the previous beauty. So in my case, I just do prediction with the model 1 time but then convert the predictions to x and x+1 in the likelihood part before calculating the probabilities

Comment: OK cool. A few more things. Please let me know the number of inducing points, the number of training iterations, the learning rate, and I figured out most of your imports except for "Normal", where is that coming from? (nvm I guess that's torch.distributions.Normal).

Comment: number of inducing points i am mostly testing with 100. normal is as you said from torch.distributions import Normal . lr i tested with many but all the configurations are giving the same result in my case. lr 0.1 and iterations 1000 is okay.

Comment: Thanks. And finally, when you say the uncertainty is equal over all input points, you mean that running: "model(X_train).stddev" yields a constant vector, right?

Comment: @JohnMadden thank you for your time. I updated the post and added how I check the uncertainty. it is predicted_variances from the code part above. you are right it is model(X_train).variance

Comment: I notice that when I run the code, the variational covariance matrix does not seem to be getting updated; the parameter "_variational_distribution.chol_variational_covar" is just the identity matrix, which is probably what it's initialized at if the authors are following the procedures of Titisias09. Regrettably, I'm not a gpytorch guy, so I'm not sure why that is; I don't seen an obvious reason for this. But I think this is a good place to start looking.

Comment: @JohnMadden thank you. I also realized that while checking the trainable parameters. I am using the same model for a completely different task in which the variational covariance matrix is not updating, but I am getting meaningful and good results. My issue is probably not caused by this but it is caused by the likelihood calculation but I am not certain about it. I will check that anyway. Thank you.

Comment: in this different task, are you still computing variances on the training set, or a different set of points?

Comment: @JohnMadden I am not using this likelihood. It is not preferential data but ordinal data, and I have a completely different likelihood in which loss is directly calculated with individual model predictions

Comment: I just mean are you still doing model(X_train) at some point, or is it model(X_test)?

Comment: @JohnMadden I found that why _variational_distribution.chol_variational_covar is just identity matrix. expected log prob is using function_dist.mean while calling forward but there is not a place that I used function_dist.variance

Comment: it may be worth looking at some other implementations of variational-bayes-based classifiers in gpytorch to make sure you've got the elbo correctly configured, because it includes that matrix in several places.

Comment: @JohnMadden that might be the problem then. right now, I give a virtual point at the end to the labels to make the label and data equal size for elbo, later I remove that in likelihood. this whole elbo part might have a problem. thank you

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. There is a "delete" button you can use to delete it.